# error called object " " is not a function or function pointer in c

Tags: c

The question was Given three points (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and (x3, y3), write a
program to check if all the three points fall on one straight line
On compiling I'm getting the error called object " " is not a function or function pointer 
The program is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sidex1,sidex2,sidex3,sidey1,sidey2,sidey3 ;
    printf("Type in the coordinates");
    scanf("%d%d %d%d %d%d", &sidex1, &sidey1, &sidex2, &sidey2, &sidex3, 
    &sidey3);
    if
    (sidex1(sidey2-sidey3)+sidex2(sidey3-sidey1)+sidex3(sidey1-sidey2)==0)
    printf("These coordinates lie on same line");
    else
    printf("These coordinates do not lie on a line");
    }
```

I'm a complete Noob. 
Thanks for Help!

Comment: What is `sidex1(sidey2-sidey3)` supposed to be?

Comment: So which line is giving the error?

Comment: You're using a variable of type `int` as a function pointer

Comment: Are you trying to multiply `sidex1` by `sidey2-sidey3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To multiple variables in pretty much any program language, you use the `*` operator like this

```
sidex1*(sidey2-sidey3)
```

rather than what you have which is

```
sidex1(sidey2-sidey3)
```

which would be confused as calling a function called `sidex1` with the parameter `sidey2-sidey3`

Comment: Yep, I was missing the * but what do you mean by sidex1 with parameter sidey2-sidey3 that you stated

Comment: @NamanGupta The way you currently have things written, i.e. `sidex1(sidey2-sidey3)` makes it look like `sidex1` is a function and `sidey2-sidey3` is the parameter to that function.  It's not a function, so that's why you got an error